# How to update sales order when order is complete

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We have a script where we send the sales orders that are already completed and ready to be invoiced but if in an order some product is needed in that warehouse the order execution is created where we must complete manually, taking into account that it has been changed the location the sales order does not update itself

I have tried to update the data that is sent by consulting item by item and updating the information to be displayed

```
var resultado = new Array();
var filters = new Array();

filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter( 'location', null, 'is', '48');
filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter( 'createdfrom', null, 'is', ordersid);

var columns = new Array();
columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('createdfrom');
columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('name','item');
columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('location');
columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('quantity');

var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('itemfulfillment', null, filters, columns);
```

In this query we obtain the item fulfillment and we obtain data to build an array that is going to be sent with the valid information then we compare the sale order with this arrangement, I do not know if I make myself explain well

Comment: When you say "completed", you mean to say "Fully Fulfilled"?
What do you mean by saying "an order some product is needed in that warehouse"?

I got confused with the scenario that you have.

Comment: Yes, I mean Fully Fulfilled

I mean that when a product hasn't inventory we need to complete from other warehouse